# Mock multiple exports in Jest + TS

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

Using:

- Typescript
- Jest
- Ts-Jest

I have the following code in `src/lib/apex/apexClient`:

```
export class ApexClient { .... }
export const newSuperUserClient = async (): Promise<ApexClient> => {
   const client = new ApexClient();
   // do stuff
   return client;
}
```

In my tests, I have the following:

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import request from 'supertest';
import { app } from '../../../src/app';
import { ApexClient } from '../../../src/lib/apex/apexClient';

jest.mock('../../../src/lib/apex/apexClient')
const mockedApexClient = mocked(ApexClient, true);

describe('POST /accounts/:accountId/withdraw_tickets/:withdrawTicketId/submit', () => {
    const ___mockedGetWithdrawTicket = mockedApexClient.prototype.getWithdrawTicket;
    const ___mockedSuperUserUpdateWithdrawTicket = mockedApexClient.prototype.updateWithdrawTicket;

    beforeEach(() => {
      ___mockedGetWithdrawTicket.mockClear();
      ___mockedSuperUserUpdateWithdrawTicket.mockClear();
    })

    describe('when Product is a NationalCurrency', () => {
        test.only('returns 200 for Pending2Fa tickets', async () => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
            // @ts-ignore
            ___mockedGetWithdrawTicket.mockResolvedValue({ Status: 'Pending2Fa', AssetId: 1 });
    
            await request(app)
                .post('/accounts/1/withdraw_tickets/TICKET_CODE/submit')
                .set('x-exchange-nonce', 'foo')
                .set('x-exchange-api-key', 'foo')
                .set('x-exchange-signature', 'foo')
                .set('x-exchange-user-id', 'foo')
                .set('x-exchange', 'true')
                .expect(200)
            
            expect(___mockedSuperUserUpdateWithdrawTicket.mock.calls[0][0]).toMatchObject({ Status: 'Submitted' })
        })
    })
})
```

I have a mock inside `spec/__mocks__/lib/apex/apexClient`:

```
import { getProducts } from "../../../__helpers__/apexRequests";

export const ___mockedGetWithdrawTicket = jest.fn();
export const ___mockedSuperUserUpdateWithdrawTicket = jest.fn();
export const ApexClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        authenticateUser: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ Authenticated: true, SessionToken: 'SESSION_TOKEN' }),
        webAuthenticateUser: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ Authenticated: true }),
        getWithdrawTicket: ___mockedGetWithdrawTicket,
        getProducts: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(getProducts()),
        closeConnection: () => true,
    }
})
export const newSuperUserClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        updateWithdrawTicket: ___mockedSuperUserUpdateWithdrawTicket.mockResolvedValue({ result: true, errormsg: '', errorcode: 0, detail: '' }),
        closeConnection: () => true,
    }
})
```

When I run the tests, it seems that its ignoring mock.
Error msg:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Authenticated')

      36 |     });
      37 |
    > 38 |     if (!authenticationResult.Authenticated) {
         |                               ^
      39 |         renderUnauthorized(res);
      40 |         return;
      41 |     }
```

However, my mock:

```
authenticateUser: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ Authenticated: true, SessionToken: 'SESSION_TOKEN' }),
```

I can get past this, and I am struggling to:

1. Mock both ApexClient class and newSuperUserClient function
2. Extract them into a reusable file inside `spec/__mocks__`. Manual mocks work, but I need a reusable solution since this is required in many tests.

jest.conf:

```
/*
 * For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
 */
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  // All imported modules in your tests should be mocked automatically
  // automock: false,

  // Stop running tests after `n` failures
  // bail: 0,

  // The directory where Jest should store its cached dependency information
  // cacheDirectory: "/tmp/jest_rt",

  // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
  clearMocks: true,

  // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
  collectCoverage: true,

  // An array of glob patterns indicating a set of files for which coverage information should be collected
  // collectCoverageFrom: undefined,

  // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",

  // An array of regexp pattern strings used to skip coverage collection
  // coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
  //   "/node_modules/"
  // ],

  // Indicates which provider should be used to instrument code for coverage
  coverageProvider: "v8",

  // A list of reporter names that Jest uses when writing coverage reports
  // coverageReporters: [
  //   "json",
  //   "text",
  //   "lcov",
  //   "clover"
  // ],

  // An object that configures minimum threshold enforcement for coverage results
  // coverageThreshold: undefined,

  // A path to a custom dependency extractor
  // dependencyExtractor: undefined,

  // Make calling deprecated APIs throw helpful error messages
  // errorOnDeprecated: false,

  // Force coverage collection from ignored files using an array of glob patterns
  // forceCoverageMatch: [],

  // A path to a module which exports an async function that is triggered once before all test suites
  // globalSetup: undefined,

  // A path to a module which exports an async function that is triggered once after all test suites
  // globalTeardown: undefined,

  // A set of global variables that need to be available in all test environments
  // globals: {},

  // The maximum amount of workers used to run your tests. Can be specified as % or a number. E.g. maxWorkers: 10% will use 10% of your CPU amount + 1 as the maximum worker number. maxWorkers: 2 will use a maximum of 2 workers.
  // maxWorkers: "50%",

  // An array of directory names to be searched recursively up from the requiring module's location
  // moduleDirectories: [
  //   "node_modules"
  // ],

  // An array of file extensions your modules use
  // moduleFileExtensions: [
  //   "js",
  //   "jsx",
  //   "ts",
  //   "tsx",
  //   "json",
  //   "node"
  // ],

  // A map from regular expressions to module names or to arrays of module names that allow to stub out resources with a single module
  // moduleNameMapper: {},

  // An array of regexp pattern strings, matched against all module paths before considered 'visible' to the module loader
  // modulePathIgnorePatterns: [],

  // Activates notifications for test results
  // notify: false,

  // An enum that specifies notification mode. Requires { notify: true }
  // notifyMode: "failure-change",

  // A preset that is used as a base for Jest's configuration
  preset: 'ts-jest',

  // Run tests from one or more projects
  // projects: undefined,

  // Use this configuration option to add custom reporters to Jest
  // reporters: undefined,

  // Automatically reset mock state between every test
  // resetMocks: false,

  // Reset the module registry before running each individual test
  // resetModules: false,

  // A path to a custom resolver
  // resolver: undefined,

  // Automatically restore mock state between every test
  // restoreMocks: false,

  // The root directory that Jest should scan for tests and modules within
  rootDir: 'spec',

  // A list of paths to directories that Jest should use to search for files in
  // roots: [
  //   "<rootDir>"
  // ],

  // Allows you to use a custom runner instead of Jest's default test runner
  // runner: "jest-runner",

  // The paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment before each test
  // setupFiles: [],

  // A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: [],

  // The number of seconds after which a test is considered as slow and reported as such in the results.
  // slowTestThreshold: 5,

  // A list of paths to snapshot serializer modules Jest should use for snapshot testing
  // snapshotSerializers: [],

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  // testEnvironment: "jest-environment-node",

  // Options that will be passed to the testEnvironment
  // testEnvironmentOptions: {},

  // Adds a location field to test results
  // testLocationInResults: false,

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  // testMatch: [
  //   "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
  //   "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  // ],

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
  // testPathIgnorePatterns: [
  //   "/node_modules/"
  // ],

  // The regexp pattern or array of patterns that Jest uses to detect test files
  // testRegex: [],

  // This option allows the use of a custom results processor
  // testResultsProcessor: undefined,

  // This option allows use of a custom test runner
  // testRunner: "jest-circus/runner",

  // This option sets the URL for the jsdom environment. It is reflected in properties such as location.href
  // testURL: "http://localhost",

  // Setting this value to "fake" allows the use of fake timers for functions such as "setTimeout"
  // timers: "real",

  // A map from regular expressions to paths to transformers
  // transform: undefined,

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
  // transformIgnorePatterns: [
  //   "/node_modules/",
  //   "\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$"
  // ],

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all modules before the module loader will automatically return a mock for them
  // unmockedModulePathPatterns: undefined,

  // Indicates whether each individual test should be reported during the run
  // verbose: undefined,

  // An array of regexp patterns that are matched against all source file paths before re-running tests in watch mode
  // watchPathIgnorePatterns: [],

  // Whether to use watchman for file crawling
  // watchman: true,
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                          /* Specify the folder for .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation files. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es6",                                /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h' */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using `jsx: react-jsx*`.` */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for `createElement`. This only applies when targeting `react` JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "rootDir": "./src",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                          /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./node_modules/*"
      ]
    },                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like `./node_modules/@types`. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow `import`s, `require`s or `<reference>`s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from `node_modules`. Only applicable with `allowJs`. */

    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    "sourceMap": true,                                   /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If `declaration` is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have `@internal` in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like `__extends` in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing `const enum` declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "spec/**/*.ts",
  ]  
}
```